# grep file with full contain string

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have some pattent and I really stuck to deal with it:

```
$order_item->meta->pickingDate = $pickingDate;
$order->meta->{'-update'} = array('status');
```

I run grep command ti list file match: **grep -r -l "->meta->"**

- Red color with *"->meta->"*

But my expect: **grep ????**

*- Red color with: *"->meta->pickingDate"* and *"meta->{'-update'}"*

I mean it match with "->meta->" and get the next string they have. How can I deal with this case ? what I have to put to grep to match with my expect ?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this,

```
grep -r -l "->meta->[^[:space:]]*" file
```

OR

```
grep -r "\b->meta->[^[:space:]]*" file
```

OR

```
grep -r -l "\b->meta->[^[:space:]]*" file
```

`[^[:space:]]*` POSIX class which matches any character but not of a space zero or more times.

Comment: very great, this grep resolve half case I have met, but some case still not match (sorry I list lack case)

"if (empty($inv_item->meta->grouped_properties)) {"

Comment: sorry unclear for me . Could you explain the case where mine won't work?

Comment: What's your expected output for the above?

Comment: Ah, in this case it will not correct "$item->meta->ndsCost)*$item->quantity;" --> red color: "->meta->ndsCost)*$item->quantity;", so my expect: "->meta->ndsCost"

Comment: Many many thank....and one more question.... "if (!empty($item->meta->system) &&" and my expect, red color: "system" (this word follow "->meta->"

Comment: try this `grep -rP -l "\b->meta->\K[^[:space:])]*"` or `grep -rP -l "\b->meta->\K\w*"`